# Push notifications with Push.js when Mysql database changes status

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, push-notification

Currently I have a PHP system orders with client and admin side, a client make an order and admin changes status according the progress of the order. Information orders are stored in MySQL database table.

For example, this is my table where I stored user account, info order and status order:

```
CREATE TABLE order (
idorder INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content_order VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(50)
);
```

When a client make an order this registers with "PENDING" status, in admin page we check this order and changes status clicking a button updating status to "PROGRESS" via AJAX, but client has to refresh his page to view the change of his order and I would like client get push notifications when his order status changes in his site.

I'm testing Push.js tool, works good. Like this example:

```
<html>
<body>
<h4>Press button</h4>
<button id="notify">Notify</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/push.js/1.0.4/push.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        if(!Push.Push.Permission.GRANTED){
            Push.Permission.request();
        }
    });

$("#btn_notificar").click(function(){
        //Push.Permission.request();

        Push.create('NOTIFICATION', {
            body: 'My first notification',
            icon: 'icon.png',
            timeout: 8000,               // Timeout before notification closes automatically.
            vibrate: [100, 100, 100],    // An array of vibration pulses for mobile devices.
            onClick: function() {
                window.focus();
                this.close();
            }  
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I integrate this notifications in client page when status changes of his orders by admin.

I would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by establishing a socket connection between user's browser and server.

Proposed flow:

- A user places an order. Browser posts the order request to the server and shows order details page. The browser also establishes a socket connection with the server which listens to status changes for newly placed order via its unique order id.
- An admin user changes the status of this order. Browser posts the order request to the server and updates the database. Server emits/broadcasts this change in status to all clients that are listening to changes for this order.
- User's browser receives this message regarding a change in status and notifies the user about the change.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logic, but what websocket would you recommend to implement in both pages?

Comment: What technology are you using in the backend? Most of the technologies support web socket connections. I have personally implemented them on node.js using [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/).